# How to get raw message text (e.g. email address) in Botkit message handler

Tags: node.js, slack-api, slack, botkit

In botkit I setup `message_received` or any other handler. When I receive message its `text` property should contain actual message written by user. Unfortunately when this message contains e.g. email address I get this message slack-formatted. Example:

user enters: `Hey, send an email to foo@bar.com`

botkit gives me: `Hey, send an email to <mailto:foo@bar.com|foo@bar.com>`

Is there a way to get it in raw form, or should I do this unwrapping by hand?

Comment: Not a heavy botkit user, but I believe this is coming straight from Slack and botkit doesn't do any further processing on it. And I am not aware of any ways to tell Slack that you wish to receive links in a raw format. I think your best bet is to unwrap this by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like :

```
var matches = response.text.match(/\|.*>/)
log.info("Matches : " + matches)
if (matches) {
    mail = matches[0].substring(1, matches[0].length - 1)
    log.info("Mail : " + mail)
}
```